# How To ReInclude Excluded Folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

So I just performed the coup de gras on my project by accidentally clicking on `Exclude From Project` instead of `Add` on my controllers folder.

When trying to add a folder named Controllers I get the error "this folder exists". However, If I try to click on the project -> `Add Existing...` I cannot select a folder, but only the controllers.

Kind of at a loss here, has anyone had experience with this, or does anyone know how to get the folders back into the solution?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Click on the `Show All Files` icon in the solution explorer and then simply include the folder:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**Visual Studio Express 2012**

Select Your Project Folder Click On "Show All Files" icon to show all Excluded Folders And Files

[image: Click On Show All Files icon to show all Excluded Folders And Files]

Then Right Click on Excluded Folder or File and Click on "Include In Project"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my ASP.Net Webforms project after excluding the file I could't find it even under 'Show all files', but they were at project folder so I had to right click on project in Visula Studio then add existing item.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone wanting a different solution, you can also browse to your project in a File Explorer and delete the offending folder (Be sure to copy it somewhere safe first!). Restart Visual Studio and proceed to add the folder as you regularly would.